SmartyException: "Unable to load template 'file:relationship2summary.tpl
I have a CiviCRM plugin in my worpdress website and I am getting following exception while clicking on single "View" in contacts :
SmartyException: "Unable to load template 'file:relationship2summary.tpl

when I check the log, it shows this
[Wed Apr 24 00:05:08 2024] [error] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/qfsessionwarning/qfsessionwarning.civix.php on line 100
[Wed Apr 24 00:10:09 2024] [error] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/qfsessionwarning/qfsessionwarning.civix.php on line 100
[Wed Apr 24 00:15:10 2024] [error] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/qfsessionwarning/qfsessionwarning.civix.php on line 100
[Wed Apr 24 00:20:11 2024] [error] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/qfsessionwarning/qfsessionwarning.civix.php on line 100
[Wed Apr 24 00:25:12 2024] [error] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/qfsessionwarning/qfsessionwarning.civix.php on line 100
[Wed Apr 24 00:30:13 2024] [error] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/qfsessionwarning/qfsessionwarning.civix.php on line 100

when I turn the debbugging on the site  it shows
```SmartyException: "Unable to load template 'file:relationship2summary.tpl'"
#0 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(232): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#1 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(116): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute()
#2 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php(85): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch()
#3 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php(161): CRM_Core_Region->{closure}()
#4 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/block.crmRegion.php(26): CRM_Core_Region->render()
#5 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/f3/5b/29/f35b29e909d609d8bb45fd8f42c1dd6f976eb4b5_0.file.CMSPrint.tpl.php(107): smarty_block_crmRegion()
#6 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_6628c9d4344768_31947081()
#7 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode()
#8 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(216): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render()
#9 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(385): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#10 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/95/72/a2/9572a2e4173d3a1d5a6acefd167c7055c31f2189_0.file.wordpress.tpl.php(31): Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender()
#11 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_6628c9d4306381_96347452()
#12 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode()
#13 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(216): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render()
#14 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(232): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#15 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(116): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute()
#16 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php(273): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch()
#17 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(122): CRM_Core_Page->run()
#18 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(325): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->run()
#19 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#20 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#21 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#22 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#23 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#24 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#25 /home/www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
#26 {main}```

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Unable to load template 'file:relationship2summary.tpl'
Return to home page.

Peter, Welcome to CiviCRM stackexchange.
Its a known issue with Smarty 3 for the Relationship2summary extension. I have pushed a fix to the extension, you apply the patch or wait for Maintainer to merge and release a new version
HTH
Pradeep

Hi Pradeep , thank you a lot . Please guide me on how to apply the patch please

You can download from https://github.com/pradpnayak/org.civicoop.relationship2summary/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

So, I should upload it to overwrite what I have there before or should i delete the files and replace it with this one. Thank you

Delete the existing one, download and untar from the above link

I have updated that, but it still shows                 Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Unable to load template 'file:relationship2summary.tpl'

Did you clear civicrm cache after the replacement?

Yes, i did and it shows a new error  Unable to load template 'file:group2summary.tpl
